# jQuery Validate + AJAX username availability check: How to marry them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

UPDATE

---

Thanks to **charlietfl's** comments and suggestions (and, at one point ire, lol - apologies for my faux pas), I've finally got the system checking from within Validate, and the form submission is halted when the email is sent. So I guess my question is answered, but if you'll all bear with me for one more moment, there's one last finishing touch that I could use your help with...

In my original vision, in addition to triggering a proper "Email already exists" error, I also populated a second element with some HTML that more completely explained the situation to the user and provided a link to a login form. This second element appeared and disappeared depending on the status of the field.

Is there a way to use the messages/remote section to do this as well?

Here what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#signup").validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.prev());
        //element.prev().replaceWith(error);
    },
    rules: {
        "email": {
            required: true,
            email:true,
            remote: {
                url: "/ajax/emailcheck.php",
                type: "post",
            },
        },
        "password": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
        },
        "password-check": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            passmatch: true,
        },
        "tos": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: " is Required",
            email: " is Improperly Formatted",
            remote: " already exists",
            },

        },
        password: {
            required: " is Required",
            minlength: " requires at least 8 characters",
        },
        "password-check": {
            required: " is Required",
            minlength: " requires at least 8 characters",
            passmatch: " must match the Passphrase",
        },
        tos: {
            required: " is Required",
            minlength: " requires at least 6 characters",
        },                      
    },
    onkeyup: true,
    onblur: true
});
```

And, in the ideal, I'd love something like this:

```
messages: {
email: {
    required: " is Required",
    email: " is Improperly Formatted",
    remote: " already exists",
    remote: {
        username: function() {
        var emailcheck = $('#email').val();  
        return $('#username_availability_result').html(emailcheck + ' is already in our system. Please <a href="/login.php">log in here</a>.');
        },
    },
},              
},
```

Thanks again, and in advance, for your own ongoing attention and advice,

Z

ORIGINAL QUESTION

---

I'm using jQuery Validate to run routine validation on a registration form. But one of the features I wanted to add to the form's functionality was an AJAX check to determine if an email address was already in the system. The problem is that the email check function exists *outside* of the validate function, and so doesn't actually stop the form from submitting when necessary.

Here's my code. (The top 50 lines comprise validation and password matching. The remainder constitutes the AJAX check [which is triggered by the email field's keyup event]).

```
        // Method adds password matching abilities to the validator
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("passmatch", function(value, element) {
           return $('#password').val() == $('#password-check').val()
        }, "* Passwords should match");

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#signup").validate({
                errorElement: "span",
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo(element.prev());
                    //element.prev().replaceWith(error);
                },
                rules: {
                    "email": {
                        required: true,
                        email:true,
                    },
                    "password": {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8,
                    },
                    "password-check": {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8,
                        passmatch: true,
                    },
                    "tos": {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6,
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: {
                        required: " is Required",
                        email: " is Improperly Formatted",
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: " is Required",
                        minlength: " requires at least 8 characters",
                    },
                    "password-check": {
                        required: " is Required",
                        minlength: " requires at least 8 characters",
                        passmatch: " must match the Password"
                    },
                    tos: {
                        required: " is Required",
                        minlength: " requires at least 6 characters",
                    },                      
                }
            });

            //check email availability 
            $('#email').keyup(function(){  
                check_availability();  
            });  

        });               

        //function to check username availability  
        function check_availability(){  

                //get the username  
                var username = $('#email').val();  

                //use ajax to run the check  
                $.post("/ajax/emailcheck.php", { username: username },  
                    function(result){  
                        //if the result greater than none  
                        if(result > 0 ){  
                            //show that the username is not available  
                            $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is already in our system. Please <a href="/login.php">log in here</a>.');  
                        }else{  
                            //username available.  
                            //clear any messages
                            $('#username_availability_result').html(''); 
                        }  
                });  
        }
```

Is there a way for the check_availability() function to trigger a stop (and a start once it's cleared) so that the form can't be submitted during a state of error? Or can the whole kit and caboodle somehow be integrated into Validate using addMethod (if so, please note that I'm providing availability feedback in a specifically IDed element, not through the same element where other Validate errors appear)?

Thanks in advance for all your help and advice.

Z

Comment: Not really an answer, so I guess a comment, but you could try using my own plugin that does pretty much what jQuery validate does plus much more... https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms. You can accomplish what you want with the `exclude` filter passing in an array of values to exclude.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I looked at your plugin and it seems pretty neat. I didn't see where it would allow me to query against my database to check if a username was available. Did I miss something?

Comment: Oh well, in reality you'll have to make your own query helper function to grab data from the database but if you save that data in an array and pass it in with the `exclude` filter then it'll get close to what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

Use the remote option of validation plugin that already has a built in ajax method that will bind to the input

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

Alternatively `required` can also be a function ( will not work on keyup or blur)

```
email:{ required: function(){
          return $('#username_availability_result').html()=='';
   }

}
```

Also, why not reset the email field if ajax returns a duplication? Your code would likely work as is with a reset of the field

Best suggestion is use built in `remote`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll start looking into the remote documentation. As for resetting the field: unless I'm misunderstanding, I wouldn't want to reset the field and erase what the user typed -- especially if they're like me and have many email addresses with the same account name at different domains (gmail, yahoo, etc) and would only backspace over that domain.

Comment: reset definitely needs to be user friendly, from code point of view is easier. But error could also include the one they tried

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#singupfrom").validate({
                rules: {

                    'useremail': {// compound rule
                        required: true,
                        email: true,



                        remote:{


                            url: "check_email.php",
                            type: "post",

                            data:
                            {
                                emails: function()
                                {
                                    return $('#singupfrom :input[name="useremail"]').val();
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }

                },
                  // here custom message for email already exists
                 messages: {
                    useremail: { remote: "Email already exists"}

                }

            });

        });
    </script>

    <!-- your user email-->

                                <label>Email :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="useremail" id="useremail" value=""  />
    <!-- your user email end -->



    // your  php file "check_email.php"  will be some thing like it 
    /// get or post can also be used in place of request depending on situation
    $email = $_REQUEST['useremail'];


    <?php 
            $check   = "your query to check the email and returns the no of rows/ emails exists ";
            if ($check == '0' or empty($check)) {
                echo 'true';
            } else {
                echo  'false';

            }

?>
```